# Suggested tweak to app feed

Tags: feature-request, tags, ios-app, ios-app-feed

<sub>(all tags in this post are stack overflow)</sub>

## Problem

#### Python

The vast majority of the questions I answer are [python](/questions/tagged/python). But that's more because there are so many questions. I almost have a gold tag badge there.

But I'm nowhere near the [top users of python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers). Of the 48,000 Python questions this year, I've answered 434 (<1%)

#### Maya

On the other hand, a more obscure tag that I actually care about is [maya](/questions/tagged/maya).It's only seen 139 questions this year but I've answered 34 of them (24%). I'm #3 [top user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maya/topusers), despite only starting this year.

Clearly, if a Maya question comes in, there's a much higher chance I'll answer it than Python, even though the total number I've answered is so small.

---

## Request

Can this be reflected in the app feed? I want to see *every* Maya question in there. My current solution is email notifications, but they're disruptive and don't go into the app.

As currently configured, I've yet to see a single Maya question show up in the feed. They don't get many votes, but are strongly relevant to me nonetheless.

#### Implementation

If the user's has answered at least 2 and more than 20% of the questions in a tag over a recent period of time, add all new questions to the feed.

As pseudocode:

```
if (user_answers(tag) / total_questions(tag) > .2 && user_answers(tag) > 2) {
    add_to_feed()
}
```